# Чтение данных с HID устройства

Tags: c++, usb, borland-c++

Передо мной  стоит следующая задача: написать программный  код в OC Windows в среде Borland C++ Builder, соотвественно, на языке С++,  который позволит  считывать значения с HID устройства, конкретнее - значения напряжения. До этого с внешними устройствами никогда не работал.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это можно сделать.

Comment: Больше конкретики, что за устройство(производитель, модель)

Comment: возможно поможет готовая либа http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/ . Если в либе чего-то не хватает, то можно глянуть код на гите. Еще, если я правильно помню, вам понадобиться DDK (driver development kit) для винды, чтобы это всё заработало

Comment: @JK_Action мне сказали, что для написания данной программы, это  не нужно.  Меня дезинформировали?

Comment: @goldstar_labs спасибо большое  за информацию

Comment: @goldstar_labs оформите свой коментарий как ответ

Comment: @Дмитрий Плотников я был не прав можно работать с hid как с абстракцией